# Определить параметры контрольной суммы CRC по значениям контрольных сумм для известных строк

Tags: криптография, hex, crc

Я новичок. Необходимо, зная контрольные суммы некоторых hex строк,
определить, с какими параметрами вычислялась контрольная сумма: `poly`, `unit`,`refin`,`refout`, `xorout`, `check`.

Каким образом можно осуществить подбор?

Comment: Первый же [запрос в гугле](https://www.google.com/search?q=crc+reverse+engineering) принёс результат: https://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/essays/CRC-Reverse-Engineering.html

Comment: @PakUula, так напишите ответ, основываясь на найденной информации.